# PDF bookmarks don't work correctly (every reference points to the first page of the document)

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, pdf, bookmarks

As I almost described in the title of this question, my problem is the following: I'm trying to create suitable PDF bookmarks to my document but all the references (bookmarks on the left side, references of equations, etc.) always jump on the first page. Earlier the document was much longer but I reduced the code as much as possible in order to make it able to post here (and demonstrate the issue).

Could somebody suggest me something or maybe give a solution for this problem? I tried a lot things by the way: modified the order of the include package statements (didn't help), use only one of the packages 'bookmark' and 'hyperref' (this wasn't good since without the bookmark package the bookmark hierarchy in Acrobat Reader was not correct and without hyperref the references was working still in an incorrect way).

At the bottom of my post I'll put the mentioned code section of this document.

(Finally, it's possible the I'll edit this post later and put some other methods and tried but didn't help to solve this problem.)

One more thing: There was a similar issue about 10 months ago but it hasn't been answered correctly so far. In further posts and questions I did not find answer for this problem.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3cm,right=2cm,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={László Zsolt},
    pdftitle={Doesn't matter},
    pdfsubject={Something},
    pdfkeywords={key, word},
    pdfproducer={MiKTeX pdfTeX-1.40.13},
    pdfcreator={PdfLaTeX},
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    bookmarksopen=true,
    bookmarksopenlevel=1,
    pdfstartview=Fit,
    unicode=true,
    pdfpagemode=UseOutlines
}
```

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{startatroot}

\onehalfspace

\begin{document}

\chapter{Elmélet}
\section{Alapfogalmak}
\subsection{A lineáris programozási modell felépítése}
\subsection{Standard alakú lineáris programozási feladat}
\subsection{Kanonikus alakú lineáris programozási feladat}
\subsection{Műveletek az alakok közötti áttéréshez}
\section{A grafikus módszer}
\subsection{Az algoritmus}
\subsection{További definíciók}

\begin{equation}\label{eq_sd}
Standard\;deviation = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \left( x_i - \bar{x} \right)^2}{n - 1}}
\end{equation}

\subsection{Speciális esetek a grafikus megoldás esetén}
\chapter{Some other chapter}

How should I calculate the standard deviation of a population? Look at equation (\ref{eq_sd}).

\chapter{One more chapter}

How should I calculate the standard deviation of a population again? Look at equation (\ref{eq_sd}).

\end{document}

Comment: (Putting the equation into an other chapter makes it easier to see that it's reference doesn't work properly.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: When I compile your example, all links point where they are supposed to. The only glitch is `\onehalfspace` that should be `\onehalfspacing`, but it doesn't influence the final result. What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: I'm trying to create this document perfectly with the following conf.: Windows 7 operating system, Texmaker 4.0.3, MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: Works perfectly fine with Windows 7, MikTeX 2.9, TeXnicCenter 2.

Comment: I can compile this without problems and correct hyperlinks/bookmarks on Linux, TeXLive 2014. `hyperref` should be the last package (in this case the next to the last past package, since `bookmark` is included too.) If this does not help, try `hypertexnames=false` as an option in `\hypersetup`

Comment: First of all I'd like to thank you for giving me information and tips! Unfortunately, I didn't manage to generate the PDF file properly nor even after reinstalling both MiKTeX and Texmaker. :( Also tried with TeXnicCenter but still no suitable results... Any other suggestions, please?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by a software update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You very much for your idea Jiri Srubar but fortunately I don't need to try because a few minutes ago I managed to solve this problem in the following way: I reinstalled MiKTeX again but before installing any of the necessary packages I used the packagemanager's 'Synchronize' option from the 'Repository' menu.
After this, I downloaded the packages the document needed and everything's just fine now (finally). :)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I usually use the "latex > dvips > ps2pdf" workflow, and for ps2pdf I'm using GPL GhostScript batch.
And it seems that GhostScript is the culprit. When I downgraded GhostScript back to version 9.02 (from 9.15), PDF bookmarks are generated correctly again. (Upgrading to 9.16 didn't help.)

(W7, MikTeX 2.9, TexStudio 2.9.4)